# Angular 4. Пункт <select> выбирается только со второго раза

Tags: typescript, angular, angular4

Есть `<select>`, есть один `<option>`, который ориентирован на `null`, остальные `<option>` формируются по `*ngFor` из массива. Проблема в следующем: если изначальное значение `null`, то при первом выборе любого другого варианта сначала в `<select>` не выбирается ни один пункт. Если снова развернуть список вариантов и выбрать какой-нибудь, только тогда он выбирается. Т.е.: 1) Начальное значение `null`, в `<select>` выводится "Не выбрано" --> 2) Выбираем любой пункт - в `<select>` вообще пусто --> 3) Снова выбираем любой пункт - в `<select>` выбранный пункт. Почему так? Как это исправить? Пробовал назначать `[select]="option.id === object.option.id"` - нулевой эффект, пробовал заменить `[value]` на `[ngValue]` - нулевой эффект. Пробовал писать `[(ngModal)]="object.option.id ? object.option.id : object.option"` - получаю ошибку, т.к. изначально `object.option: null`. Полный код верстки выпадающего списка:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="object.option ? object.option.id : object.option">
  <option [value]="null">Не выбрано</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of options" [value]="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

`orbject.option` - тут может быть только одна опция. Если опция есть, то она - объект с атрибутом id - `object.option.id`.

```
{
 object: {
  option: {
   id: 11111
  }
 }
}
```

Если опции нет, то она `null`.

```
{
 object: {
  option: null
 }
}
```

Массив `options` - справочник всех возможных опций.
Сделал пример: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jk1n2d?file=src%2Fapp%2Foptions%2Foptions.component.html
Подозреваю, что дело в проверке в `[(ngModel)]`, мне необходимо работать с `object.option.id`, но если я без проверки напрямую укажу его, то в случае `object.option: null` вылетает ошибка и приложение падает.

Comment: сделайте пожалуйста пример на stackblitz

Comment: @overthesanity cделал: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jk1n2d?file=src%2Fapp%2Foptions%2Foptions.component.html](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jk1n2d?file=src%2Fapp%2Foptions%2Foptions.component.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В директиву `ngModel` не нужно передавать условия никогда :) Все, что вам нужно это дополнительная переменная, которая будет хранить выбранную опцию. Пускай это будет `selectedOption`:

```
options = [
  { id: '111', name: 'Option 1' },
  { id: '222', name: 'Option 2' },
  { id: '333', name: 'Option 3' },
];

public selectedOption = null;
```

Изначально `null`, потому что ни одна опция не выбрана. В директиву `ngModel` с двусторонним байндингом передаем это свойство:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
  <option [value]="null">Не выбрано</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of options" [value]="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>

<p>{{ selectedOption }}</p>
```

Я добавил параграф просто для наглядности, чтобы бы вы убедились, что свойство меняется и принимает значение, которое вы указали в байндинге атрибута `value` :)

Если же вам нужно вручную отслеживать изменение модели, то используем односторонний байндинг и делаем подписку на генератор событий `ngModelChange`:

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedOption" (ngModelChange)="selectedOptionChanged($event)">
    ...
</select>
```

В компоненте создадим этот метод:

```
public selectedOptionChanged(id: number): void {
    console.log(id);
}
```

Но заметьте, что в случае с односторонним байндингом значение самого свойства `selectedOption` изменяться не будет, поэтому делайте расчет на аргумент `id`.

Comment: Спасибо) Это то, что нужно)